# DocuSign embedded sending - view tag placement

Tags: docusignapi

I am using a SOAP based API call - **CreateAndSendEnvelope** to create envelopes into
specified DocuSign accounts. I pre-configure the recipients and tags outside of 
DocuSign console and pass in pre-configured recipient/tag information in the **CreateandSendEnvelope**
API call request.

At times, I need to vary the tag positions a few times before I configure the correct
tag placement for the recipients. I always have to create the envelopes to check tag positions.
I am looking into an option of using **Embedded sending** option to preview the tag
placement for the envelope but I found out that in order to use Embedded sending
I actually have to create an envelope first and then pass in the envelope id to
preview the tags/correct tags.

Is there a way to preview the recipient/tags without creating an envelope
using Embedded sending option or any other option?

Comment: I do not believe there's a way to preview what the tags for a given recipient without creating the underlying envelope.  What exactly are you trying to avoid or accomplish here?  You can create the envelope but not send it right away, then do an embedded sending for the first recipient and if they need to alter tags they can, if not they can just send.  In the end it's all just one envelope still, so is there something else I'm missing in this flow?  Thx

Comment: I am trying to view the tag placement before sending out an envelope to the recipients. I think, you answered my question here - an envelope gets created to allow me to view the tag placement but I can decide not to send out to the recipients if the tags placement is not correct using Embedded sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so we have a logged answer for the benefit of the community, you need to create an underlying envelope to be able to preview tag placements... but as mentioned you can create the envelope and set the status to "created" which simply saves it as a draft ready to be sent at a later time.

Comment: I tried creating Embedded sending view using the SOAP based API call "RequestSenderToken" which created an envelope first and then opened up DocuSign console and opened the document to be signed. I did not get the Tag and Sign view that I wanted. Upon further research, I found out that in order to get Tag and Sign view I need to create an envelope using a template, create an envelope and set the status to "created" and then use Embedded signing..